# how get the value of one particular variable out of a function without actually running it

Tags: python, function, variables, user-defined-functions

the code given below is part of a bigger program.
i want to get the value of 'phone' out of the function, without actually running the function
(like only need 'phone' and i dont want 'val' to get printed)

```
def signup():

    n = input('enter name : ')
    db = input('enter date of birth : ')
    phone = int(input('enter phone number : '))
    ad = input('enter address : ')
    password = input('enter password : ')
    accnt = input('enter account no : ')
    val = (accnt, n, password, db, ad, phone)
    print(val)
```

Comment: If you never call the function, `input` is never called, the user never types the value and `phone` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To get password you should call `password = input(...)` somewhere but you can't run only one specific line of a function without running all the function. However you can refactor your code with two functions to get what you want:

```py
def get_password():
    """Get password from user."""
    password = input('enter password : ')
    return password

def signup():
    """Ask user to sign up."""
    n = input('enter name : ')
    db = input('enter date of birth : ')
    phone = int(input('enter phone number : '))
    ad = input('enter address : ')
    password = get_password()  # change here
    accnt = input('enter account no : ')
    val = (accnt, n, password, db, ad, phone)
    print(val)
```

Then call `get_password` to get password value.